# Determining focal statistics in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, focal-statistics

I'm curious to know what is the counterpart for ArcGIS focal statistics tool in QGIS?

Comment: What are the requirements that you are trying to meet for focal statistics in QGIS?

Comment: You should at least include the description of the Arc tool in your question. When you're asking people to volunteer their time to help you with your problem, don't expect them waste time searching for information that you could have provided in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From QGIS Processing Toolbox, we can access GRASS `r.neighbors` tool.

Available options (statistics) are slightly different each other.

**Both ArcGIS Focal statistics / GRASS r.neighbors**

- Mean (average)
- Minimum
- Maximum
- Median
- Majority (Mode)
- STD
- Sum

**Focal statistics**

- Range
- Variety
- Minority

**r.neighbors**

- Variance
- Interspersion
- Diversity

(I cannot find *Range* in r.neighbors now -QGIS 2.18- for some unknown reason.)